# Laravel 5.4 - "php artisan migrate" shows nothing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migrate

I just got started with Laravel and I connected my application to my mysql database. I created an additional migration file, but when I run the `php artisan migrate`, nothing happens. I tried waiting for even 10 minutes but absolutely nothing. When I connect to the mysql service and select the database to show tables there are 0 results. Something is happening and it just doesn't want to migrate. Thanks for helping.

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention that any `migrate` command does not work.
Example: `php artisan migrate`, `php artisan migrate:rollback`, `php artisan migrate:status`.
It just sits there with no output until I end it manually.

SOLUTION: So it seems like the problem was that the user I was trying to connect with didn't have the proper privileges. For some reason, mysql was kind enough not to give me any feedback and letting me figure it out.

Comment: can you try php artisan migrate:status & check what it says. Can you also check if the migration exists in the migrations folder?

Comment: The migration exists. I should have also add that any artisan command starting with `migrate` doesn't do anything (no output either). The `php artisan make:migration` works ok and also outputs the result.